# как избавиться от отступа при flex-wrap?

Tags: html, css

```css
.block {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 750px
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/901545/edit#
```

[image]

Когда все элементы помещаются в flex ряду, то все нормально, но стоит одному элементу вылезти, как появляется отступ справа. Как от этого избавиться?
Justift-content: space-around, space-between не подойдет, отступ между блоками должен быть фиксированный.

Comment: покажите свой код помогу..

Comment: пробовали `justify-content: space-between`?

Comment: И как Вы себе это представляете, если ширина блоков - фикс., отступы - фикс. "Justift-content: space-around, space-between не подойдет" ? Тогда только резиновую ширину блокам задавать